# Медленная отрисовка при использовании transaction add

Tags: java, android, kotlin

использую библиотеку cicerone и метод  router.navigateTo(screen,false) которые отрисовывает 2 фрагмент поверх первого т.е аналогия add.

Вторым фрагментом является web view. В первом и во втором фрагменте никаких сложных операций не выполняется.

Проблема: при отладке наложения GPU медленная отрисовка кадров. Какое решение есть этой проблемы? Отказаться полностью от транзакции add ? Это ведь тоже странно.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

Элементам присвоить элементам верстки android:saveEnabled="true" и заменить add на replace.